# SQL - How to choose the lowest value from values with another condition?

Tags: sql, union, where-clause, min

I need to find products (ProductName) supplied by companies (CompanyName) that names' start between letters 'a' and 'g' and then show the cheapest one (UnitPrice). I tried to find an answer, but I cannot seem to get it right - I seem to just find the overall minimal value, not the minimal value from the already chosen products. I would really appreciate help and some explanation!

Code that just selects products based on company name:

```
SELECT
    'The cheapest' ttype,
    p.ProductName, 
    s.CompanyName, 
    c.CategoryName,
    p.UnitPrice
FROM
    dbo.Products p
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Categories c
    ON
    c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Suppliers s
    ON
    s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
WHERE
    SUBSTRING(CompanyName, 1, 1) > 'a' and SUBSTRING(CompanyName, 1, 1) < 'g'
```

Tried:

```
    AND
    UnitPrice = (
        SELECT
            MIN(UnitPrice)
        FROM
            Products
    )
```

and:

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Products pr WHERE pr.UnitPrice < p.UnitPrice)
```

and using SELECT TOP 1 [...] ORDER BY UnitPrice Asc, however (!) I need to make an union later on (pick the most expensive product as well) and ORDER BY doesn't work with UNION, apparently.

Sorry if the code isn't the best - I'm new to SQL. Thank you for your time!

Comment: If you want to include companies starting with A and G then you need to use >= and <= as the operators. Also you are assuming the server is configured to be case-insensitive (which it is by default).

Answer (score 1):

```
    AND
    UnitPrice = (
        SELECT
            MIN(UnitPrice)
FROM
    dbo.Products p
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Categories c
    ON
    c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Suppliers s
    ON
    s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
WHERE
    SUBSTRING(CompanyName, 1, 1) >= 'a' and SUBSTRING(CompanyName, 1, 1) =< 'g'
)
```

Comment: Ohh, thank you! Was working with what previous comment gave me and messing with adding INNER JOINs, but didn't get that far yet. It worked! Thank you a lot.Could you only tell me if it's possible to do it in a quicker or "prettier way"? Seems kinda messy, to use the same INNER JOINs twice in one SELECT.

Comment: It's not the most elegant alright. The other answer is a more elegant approach. I think it will work if you change it like this: [...your first query...] as p1 p1.UnitPrice = (SELECT MIN(p2.UnitPrice)
             FROM Products p2
             WHERE p2.ProductName = p1.ProductName
            )

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "[...your first query...] as p1"? Where am I supposed to write it? I swear it doesn't work anywhere like it's supposed to work. ):<

Comment: Oh sorry. It's hard in the comment format. I mean you could give your first query that finds the products an alias of p1 and then use Gordon Linoff's answer but with p replaced with p1.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are other ways, what you are looking for is a correlation clause:

```
UnitPrice = (SELECT MIN(p2.UnitPrice)
             FROM Products p2
             WHERE p2.ProductName = p.ProductName
            )
```

Comment: Well, it... did not work, haha - it just shows the products that it shows just with the first condition (>='a' && <='g') And where I seem to get, where you are coming from, I cannot seem to get it to work correctly anyway.